# Print some text lines using Crystal Report formula

Tags: c#-4.0, printing, crystal-reports, formula

I have some idea how to accomplish this task but I am stuck in between.
I want to print some lines based on the count of a value field in my crystal reports.

I check the number of co-applicants and based on the count, I want to print exact signature area, where they can do their signature when print outs will be taken.

Is there any way to do so?
What is the function which we use to print lines, just tell me this, rest I will manage.

Comment: Is there a maximum number of co-applicants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific print function, the result of the last line of any formula is what is printed.  The easiest thing to do for calculated text output is to create a local StringVar for the output, and then have the very last line of the function be just the name of that variable (which will print the contents of the variable).

Another thing that may help: using return/newline ("\r\n") will work in a Crystal text field if you use the character codes.  `"line1" + chr(13) + chr(10) + "line2"`  Just be sure to set the "Can Grow" option on the field.